# Changing perspective causes popup error, debug perspective no longer functional

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

Just installed Eclipse Juno, having problems with perspectives since then.  In addition to the editor window being very small and confined to one corner of the display (in Debug; it's okay in Java perspective), I am getting errors when changing perspectives.  Suggestions?  I'm going to go back to Indigo if I can't fix this.

When I switch from the Debug perspective to the Java perspective I get a popup titled "Problem Occurred."  The text in the popup reads:
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.

```
org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.findPerspective(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IPerspectiveDescriptor;)Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/Perspective;

The error log shows a stacktrace which starts:
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2012-11-26 12:56:50.841
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.findPerspective(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IPerspectiveDescriptor;)Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/Perspective;
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.GdtPlugin.maybeAddNewWizardActionsToPerspective(GdtPlugin.java:302)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.GdtPlugin.access$0(GdtPlugin.java:295)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.GdtPlugin$1.perspectiveActivated(GdtPlugin.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList$1.run(PerspectiveListenerList.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.fireEvent(PerspectiveListenerList.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.firePerspectiveActivated(PerspectiveListenerList.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.firePerspectiveActivated(WorkbenchWindow.java:1260)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$4.handleEvent(WorkbenchPage.java:2834)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the steps below:

1. Start your `eclipse` with clean option as `eclipse -clean`. If  you are using the shortcut then go to properties and add `-clean` in the `target`.
2. Go to the `debug` perspective, right click the `debug` icon in right top corner and select `reset`.

Hope this fixes your problem.