# Eclipse: exception switching perspectives after upgrade to Juno

Tags: eclipse

I recently upgraded from Indigo to Juno, and while so far everything seems to be working ok, I'm getting an exception every time I switch perspectives:

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.findPerspective(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IPerspectiveDescriptor;)Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/Perspective;

In the log there's the following:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2013-08-01 13:52:11.378 !MESSAGE
>   Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in:
>   "org.eclipse.ui.workbench". !STACK 0 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.findPerspective(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IPerspectiveDescriptor;)Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/Perspective;
>     at
>   org.eclipse.papyrus.ui.perspectiveconfiguration.PapyrusPerspectiveListener.perspectiveActivated(PapyrusPerspectiveListener.java:117)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList$1.run(PerspectiveListenerList.java:74)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:857)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.fireEvent(PerspectiveListenerList.java:58)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.firePerspectiveActivated(PerspectiveListenerList.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.firePerspectiveActivated(WorkbenchWindow.java:1264)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$4.handleEvent(WorkbenchPage.java:2805)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4299)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:380)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.perspectiveswitcher.PerspectiveSwitcher$13.widgetSelected(PerspectiveSwitcher.java:439)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

I found [the report of a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570592/changing-perspective-causes-popup-error-debug-perspective-no-longer-functional), where it is suggested a restart with the *-clean* option should bring things back to normal. In my case it didn't work out.

Any clues on how to solve this issue are welcome. Thank you.

**Update**: I tried to upgrade to Kepler but I get this error:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
>   2.0.1.20130919-0803 (epp.package.jee 2.0.1.20130919-0803)   Software currently installed: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools SDK
>   3.4.2.v201211061806-7A7B58DXJVWwZEWDH3nUMVrrpMjAA0fXe5BCATMT (org.eclipse.wst.xml_sdk.feature.feature.group
>   3.4.2.v201211061806-7A7B58DXJVWwZEWDH3nUMVrrpMjAA0fXe5BCATMT)   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>       Help System UI 4.0.1.v20130708-1201 (org.eclipse.help.ui 4.0.1.v20130708-1201)
>       Help System UI 3.5.100.v20110425 (org.eclipse.help.ui 3.5.100.v20110425)
>       Help System UI 3.5.200.v20120521-2344 (org.eclipse.help.ui 3.5.200.v20120521-2344)
>       Help System UI 3.5.201.v20130108-092756 (org.eclipse.help.ui 3.5.201.v20130108-092756)
>       Help System UI 3.5.101.r37_20110819 (org.eclipse.help.ui 3.5.101.r37_20110819)
>       Help System UI 4.0.0.v20130515-1955 (org.eclipse.help.ui 4.0.0.v20130515-1955)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 2.0.1.20130919-0803 (epp.package.jee 2.0.1.20130919-0803)
>       To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [2.0.1.20130919-0803]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Java EE IDE Feature 2.0.1.20130919-0803 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group
>   2.0.1.20130919-0803)
>       To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.3.1.v20130911-1000]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse Help System 2.0.1.v20130911-1000 (org.eclipse.help.feature.group 2.0.1.v20130911-1000)
>       To: org.eclipse.help.ui [4.0.1.v20130708-1201]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse Platform 4.3.1.v20130911-1000 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.3.1.v20130911-1000)
>       To: org.eclipse.help.feature.group [2.0.1.v20130911-1000]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: WST Common Plug-in Developer Resources 3.4.2.v201212051536-7979AC9xPEJWmZP3qnoEgVwMz0iMF1-Up_QmsEDo (org.eclipse.wst.common_sdk.feature.feature.group
>   3.4.2.v201212051536-7979AC9xPEJWmZP3qnoEgVwMz0iMF1-Up_QmsEDo)
>       To: org.eclipse.wst.validation.doc.isv [1.2.200.v201004280700]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Validation Framework - Developer Guide 1.2.200.v201004280700 (org.eclipse.wst.validation.doc.isv 1.2.200.v201004280700)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.help.ui [3.2.0,4.0.0)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools SDK 3.4.2.v201211061806-7A7B58DXJVWwZEWDH3nUMVrrpMjAA0fXe5BCATMT (org.eclipse.wst.xml_sdk.feature.feature.group
>   3.4.2.v201211061806-7A7B58DXJVWwZEWDH3nUMVrrpMjAA0fXe5BCATMT)
>       To: org.eclipse.wst.common_sdk.feature.feature.group [3.4.2.v201212051536-7979AC9xPEJWmZP3qnoEgVwMz0iMF1-Up_QmsEDo]

Comment: now upgrade to kepler :p

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Oh, wait. Your question is a bit unclear. Are you having trouble with the Juno IDE or your own Eclipse project? If it's the IDE, reinstall the thing. If it's you own project, keep reading.

---

Firstly, you need to switch the core dependencies to the new target platform.

Go to **plugin.xml** -> **Dependencies** -> Remove the **org.eclipse.ui** and **org.eclipse.core.runtime** (I'm guessing you have these. You have any more of eclipse's plug-ins, make sure to remove them as well) then **add them again**!

Secondly, remember to include all of your required plug-in from the **Debug Configurations** window.

Go there, go to **Plug-ins**, deselect **Target Platform**, click **Add Required Plug-ins**, click **Validate**, then **Apply** and run it.

Comment: Your answer is a bit unclear. Where can I find the plugin.xml menu? It sure looks like a file name to me.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa So is it your own project or not? What do you mean you can't find the `plugin.xml` menu? Just double click the thing, and you have access to all the stuff you need.

Comment: I've flagged this answer, it doesn't seem to answering my question.